# what is stopping my screen from rendering as planned?

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1); 
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 

combattext.setText(combatstring);



stage.act();
stage.draw();    
}
```

combatstring is a string that displays what happened in my game.  when enemies attacks, it says what happened.  when I attack, it says what happens.  As of now my game has a loop when in combat that runs a turncounting instance.  When it's time for a turn, it runs that participants turn, and when their turn is over it updates combatstring.

I have 2 combatstrings.  One is for my characters, and one is for enemies.  Here is an example of what happens when it's an enemies turn.

```
if(thisencounter.monster1turn){  //monster1's turn goes in here

    thiscombat.getTarget(1);     //get enemy's target

    thiscombat.calculateVars(1); //calculate all combat variables for
                                 // this turn
    thiscombat.theyAttack();    

    combatstring = thisencounter.thisenemy.species+
                   " "+thiscombat.action+
                   " "+thiscombat.theirtarget.species+
                   " for "+thiscombat.effect;

    thisencounter.monster1turn=false;

}
```

This works fine, my combattext label updates instantly when a monster goes.

For my characters, their turns make buttons visible on my screen.  The buttons have listeners that determine actions, here is an example:

```
    monster1.addListener(new ClickListener(){ //makes the first enemy's 
                                              //image clickable, but only 
                                              //when the attack button 
                                              //has been clicked
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {

    thiscombat.ChooseTarget(1); //various methods that calculate damage,
                                //output what happened, and put us back in 

    thiscombat.calculateVars(4); //the loop to wait for next 
                                 //participant's turn
    thiscombat.youAttack();

    combatstring = thisencounter.thisspirit.species+
                   " "+thiscombat.action+
                   " "+thiscombat.yourtarget.species+
                   " for "+thiscombat.effect;

    monster1.clear();
    monster2.clear();
    monster3.clear();


        try {
            combatloop();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(map1field.class.getName()).
                             log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

   }});
```

This also works fine, EXCEPT on the turn just before a monster goes.  Since there is no wait between my turn and the monster's turn, the combattext just instantly displays what the monster does.

I assumed 'oh hey this is because there is no delay between the two turns'.  So, I threw a thread.sleep(2000) just before where it updates the monsters combatstring.

But that does not fix it.  It still does not show the text for my character that goes just before a monster.  Also, since fighting starts right when you go to this screen in the game, it waits about 2 seconds before it displays anything on the screen.

For the life of me I don't understand why it behaves like this.  Can someone explain what is happening to me?  Is it because it isn't rendering before it gets to thread.sleep ?

If that's the case, how do I force it to render before it does thread.sleep, or what should I be using instead of thread.sleep ?

Comment: Everything in Libgdx happens on the same thread so sleeping the thread merely freezes the entire game. Look up scene2d Actions in the libgdx documentation. You can creat a sequence action that consists of a DelayAction followed by a RunnableAction that changes the text.

Comment: I would suggest adding logging information so that you can see what (in your code) is being called and in which order: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Logging